# Proper simple exception handling

Tags: java, exception

What should we do in `catch` block when we can't do anything useful for program work recovery? Say it's simple program, so Logging does not suitable too. For example:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(Paths.get("SomeFile.txt"));
        //...
    } catch (IOException exc){
        //System.out.println("Error"); — erroneous, right?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What would you like to see when such an exception (not error) occurs? You can print the stack trace for example, print an error message (prefer `System.err` for that), or anything else that helps you identify the wrong behaviour.. I usually prefer just `System.err.println(exc)` in the catch block (Exceptions have a `toString()` method, too!)

Comment: If you can't recover, just don't catch at all.

Comment: What do you mean by simple program? Do you mean a program that you wrote for understanding a Java API?

Comment: I've read that  print the stack trace is bad practice.

Comment: @bot I mean program that someone could see, but it isn't some project or something like that.

Comment: @DmytroD So its for educational purposes right?

Comment: @bot not only, see my comment below Eran answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple program, either do nothing (don't catch the exception, add `throws` clause to your main method), or print some error message in the catch block (preferably to System.err). The latter option only makes sense if there is no more code after the catch block (since you don't want to execute any code after the exception is caught).

Comment: In simple program i mean a program, that someone could see and for example say something about bad/good style programing.